# average by class -- unix (awk)

Tags: unix, awk

Lets say that we have a file like:
`1 0.456
1 0.847 
1 0.493 
1 0.349 
2 0.189 
2 0.794 
2 0.639 
3 0.974 
3 0.784 
3 0.649 
3 0.397 
3 0.985`

I would like to have the average per class, like:
`1 0.53625 
2 0.5406 
3 0.7578`

I could have the total average using:
`awk '{total+=$2} END {print total/NR}'`
but that's not the case.

It is worth to say that the classes have different number of rows.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use arrays for this:

```
$ awk '{a[$1]+=$2;b[$1]++}END{for(i in a){print i,a[i]/b[i]}}' file
1 0.53625
2 0.540667
3 0.7578
```

The array `a` holds the sum of element per categary. The array `b` holds the number of elements per category.

The `END` statement goes through the array and print the average.

Comment: Nice! It worked perfectly. I still learning how to use these arrays. 
Thank you @oliv !

Answer (score 1):

[Cumulative moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Cumulative_moving_average), ie. it doesn't store each value in memory, just the averages and counts:

```
$ awk '{a[$1]=(c[$1]*a[$1]+$2)/++c[$1]}END{for(i in a)print i, a[i]}' file
1 0.53625
2 0.540667
3 0.7578
```

Explained, well commented at least:

```
$ awk '
{
    a[$1]=(c[$1]*a[$1]+$2)/++c[$1]   # CMA
}
END {
    for(i in a)                      # loop all entries
        print i, a[i]                # output
}' file
```

Notice, that output order is awk default.

Comment: Very interesting. Thank you!

Comment: @james-brown Why order in (mac os) is `2, 3, 1` and not `1,2,3`?

Comment: @nbari https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Array-Traversal.html#Controlling-Array-Traversal : _By default, the order in which a ‘for (indx in array)’ loop scans an array is not defined; it is generally based upon the internal implementation of arrays inside awk. _